# Add whitespace after header and remove page number

Tags: spacing, header-footer

I am writing a short document which I need to fit all on 1 page. I am trying to squeeze everything on there, and because I'm short of space, I wanted my name and title just to be a header right at the top.

I have used:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\footnotesize \parbox{11cm}{Title of Document} }
\rhead{\footnotesize {My Name} }
\renewcommand\headheight{14pt}
```

to do this. This, however, has introduced a page number at the bottom of the page that I don't want. I have used:

```
\usepackage{nopageno}
```

but it doesn't seem to help.

Finally, My text begins immediately under the header, but I would like a blank line of two. I have tried

```
\newline
```

and also

```
\vspace
```

but neither seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to redefine the margins and `\textheight` a little larger, rather than trying to use a solution involing headers?

Comment: To remove the page number you also can define all the fields created with the `fancyhdr` as empty. There are 6 fields by default l,r and c for head and foot. Example:`\rfoot{}`. This would also allow you to be aware of which fields exist and what you have put in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use as much space as possible, use the classoption `twocolumn`. Remove the pagenumber by using `\thispagestyle{empty}` somewhere after `\begin{document}`. Enlarge the page by `\enlargethispage{Xem}`, for X put a number, something like 5 should do.

For your needs use the starred form of `\vspace`, e.g. `\vspace*{2\baselineskip}`.

Buy a book about LaTeX for beginners, it will help you a lot.